# Ctrl+V not working in PyCharm Community Edition on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, paste, ctrl

[image: keymap in settings]

<kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> shortcut does not work inside Pycharm. <kbd>Shift+Insert</kbd> works and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+v</kbd> works as well. Also <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> works just fine.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing PyCharm with all available ways (snap, standalone, JetBrains toolbox etc), I have no plugins (vim or other) enabled and I have tried the command with different keyboard languages. I cannot edit the keymap settings of the paste command. Whenever I try to edit the keymap shortcut command and press the key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, it ignores it.

Comment: Check your settings (in PyCharm). PyCharm has various keyboard settings (to be compatible with other editors). It seems you selected one without C-V for pasting.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-keymap.html

Comment: I have added a screenshot in the issue. As mentioned in the issue's description, I have checked the keymap settings and whenever I try to edit the keymap shortcut command and press the key Ctrl, it ignores it. However, the default settings of the paste command include the shortcuts Ctrl+V and Shift+insert, but the Ctrl+V does not work. Is there a chance there is a conflict with Ubuntu shortcuts?

Comment: OK I found an Ubuntu shortcut I had created a long time ago for the terminal, to set Ctrl+V as paste. It seems this was conflicting with PyCharm shortcuts. I removed it and Ctrl+V is working in PyCharm.

Comment: This is a strange problem description, see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/925563) and perhaps [ask on ubuntu.se](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=pycharm) you can also try asking on [JetBrains bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) from the problem description it's something with the OS not with the IDE.

Comment: Try duplicating the keymap (to do so press the cog icon next to the keymap name and it's the first link from the top). It might be that the keymap file is read-only (also try other keymaps), after you duplicate the keymap try editing it and find the file to see if it has write permission set.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. Ubuntu does not appear to handle foreign languages correctly. Specifically, the `ibus-daemon`.

I had to run `killall ibus-daemon`

This has the unfortunate side effect of assassinating my Chinese keyboard as well since it is reliant on ibus. It does however fix the problem and restore functionality to pycharm.